# Executar função com temporizador em Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, funções

Preciso de ajuda para criar uma função em *javascript*/*jquery* que faça o seguinte:

- Ao usuário acessar meu site, inicia contador de tempo.
- Se a pessoa tentar fechar a janela/aba do navegador antes de determinado tempo, ex. 5 seg, então executa uma função.
- Agora se a pessoa passar mais de 5 seg no site a função não será executada.

Comment: Já tentou usar beforeunload? Aqui explica mais ou menos como é
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/how-to-capture-the-browser-window-close-event#1632004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se é isso :)

```js
var contador = 5;

setTimeout(temporizador,1000);

function temporizador() {
  if(contador > 0){
    setTimeout(temporizador,1000);
  } else {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
  }
  document.getElementById('tempo').innerHTML = contador;
  contador--;
}

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  // chama função
  return "Chamar uma função antes do tempo";
}
```

```html
<p> Tempo restante: 
    <span id="tempo" />
</p>
```

Comment: Exatamente isto Maicon Carraro, valeu!